# R Shiny + select2 tag inputs

Tags: r, jquery-select2, shiny

I have gotten R shiny working with select2 by using the code available here:

https://github.com/mostly-harmless/select2shiny/tree/master/inst/select2shiny

How can I use select2's tag inputs?

I'm OK editing the 'tools.js' file directly if I need to,
but I would prefer a setup that I could set the type of input in UI or Server.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean like this? http://jsfiddle.net/john_s/xra9k/

Comment: I was using a dataset (the options) loaded by server.r, and needed it in r format;

but I have switched to using Selectize which seems to more actively maintained, and a better use case for my purpose.

Comment: Selectize looks great, have you checked out https://github.com/gustavohenke/bselect